# How to expand data source automatically in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

Everyday a new line of data is appended in a Excel file, and there is a chart illustrating the data. The chart data range is like **='Sheet1'!$H$2:$I$8**, and after appending a new line to the Excel file, I have to manually modify the data source to **='Sheet1'!$H$2:$I$9**, is there any simpler way of doing this, i.e, to make chart data source expand automatically when new data is append?

BTW, I'm using Excel 2007.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format your data table into an Excel Table.  Do this by highlighting the data range and tapping Ctrl+T.  Or go to the insert menu and click table.

That should be enough.  When you add rows to the bottom of the table, the table size will increase automagically in Excel 2007.  The graph will update the range automatically, too, if the graph's range matches the table.  If not, you may need to go into the graph and re-select the data range to match the table.